# Page code stops executing after UNION sql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm still a beginner in writing PHP code.
From couple of hours I'm trying to write a script which takes results from two database tables and displays results (in do while loop)+ pagination. 
The problem I can not fix is if there are no result - the script stops page executing and it looks cut in half.

This is the query:

```
$query = "SELECT phId FROM photographers WHERE phCity=$row_cities[cityId] UNION SELECT pservOwner FROM phServices WHERE pservOwner = $row_prePhotographer[phId] AND pservService=$row_service[serviceId] LIMIT $redove, $broinastranica";

            $query_params = array();

            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex) {
                die(fusllPageError("Error","System error 103."));
            }

            $row_photographers = $stmt->fetch();

            if(!empty($row_photographers['phId'])) {
do { ... } while($row_photographers = $stmt->fetch());
else {
 echo "<h1>There are no results</h1>
 <p class=\"text-center\">Please check again after few days.</p>";
}
```

Can you please give it a look and tell what i do wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you possibly have an empty row in your table? Personally, I would check for results using PDOStatement::rowCount() instead of with the mpty($row_photographers['phId'])

Comment: I think 'Limit' has to the be the last statment in the query

Comment: Yep, the LIMIT clause is at the end of the query. $broinastranica and $redove are passing numbers (that determines the pagination - page and how many items to be shown per page).

Answer (score 0):

Check the phId from the first select and pservOwner from second select statements are of same datatype.

Try to use parentheses for each select statement. Like 
(Select id1 from table1)
Union
(select id2 from table2)

Comment: Hi, I already tried to put in (...) the two Selects, unfortunately that didn't helped.
Both phId and pservOwner are INT fields with same length so it must be fine.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the solution was very simple. Using single quotes around the values for each WHERE statement did the trick.

Here is how the query looks now:

```
$query = "SELECT phId FROM photographers WHERE phCity='$row_cities[cityId]' UNION ALL SELECT pservOwner FROM phServices WHERE pservOwner = '$row_prePhotographer[phId]' AND pservService='$row_service[serviceId]' LIMIT $redove, $broinastranica";
```

Thank you guys for your assistance.